# Angular 8 adding component dynamically "viewContainerRef of undefined" error

Tags: components, angular8, programmatically-created

I'm learning Angular and attempting to add a component to my HTML programmatically. However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewContainerRef' of undefined
```

The following are the key parts of code.

My Placeholder directive:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPlaceholder]'
})
export class PlaceholderDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Main.component.ts:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(PlaceholderDirective, {static: false, read: ViewContainerRef}) alertHost: PlaceholderDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showMyComp();
  }

  private showMyComp() {
    const testCmpFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TestComponent);
    const hostViewContainerRef = this.alertHost.viewContainerRef;
    hostViewContainerRef.clear();

    hostViewContainerRef.createComponent(testCmpFactory);
  }
}
```

Main.component.html:

```
<ng-template appPlaceholder></ng-template>
```

I have narrowed the issue down to `const hostViewContainerRef = this.alertHost.viewContainerRef;` in MainComponent.ts. The problem is that **this.alertHost** is null but I have been unable to figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue a few days ago:
Method that uses *alertHost* is invoked from **ngOnInit()**.

To make sure that the references injected by @ViewChild are present, ***always*** write initialization code using **ngAfterViewInit()**.

In addition to invoking showMyComp from ngAfterViewIinit, I had to update @ViewChild to following:

@ViewChild(PlaceholderDirective, {static: false}) alertHost: PlaceholderDirective;

(it is possible that this part is caused by different angular version)